# AngularJS override directive controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the problem. I have some 3rd party directive called **main-directive**.

```
app.directive('mainDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      foo: '&'
      // attrs
    },
    controller: function($scope) {

      $scope.click = function() {
        window.alert($scope.foo());
      }

    },
    template: '<button ng-click="click()">Click me</button>'
  }
});
```

So I want to make my own directive called **parent-directive** which assign application specific default values to third party directive attributes.

```
app.directive('parentDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      foo: '&?',
      attr2: '='
        // lots of attrs
    },
    controller: function($scope) {


      $scope.attr1 = "some default value"

      $scope.foo = function() {
        return "not overrided"
      }

      if (this.foo) {
        $scope.foo = this.foo
      }

    },
    template: '<div class="some-styling"><main-directive foo="foo()" attr1="attr1" attr2="attr2"></main-directive></div>'
  }
});
```

What if I want to make another **child-directive** that keeps **parent-directive** logic.
Overloading attribute is easy i can use "compile" function. But what about overriding functions is it possible?

```
app.directive('childDirective', function() {

  return {
    scope: false,
    require: 'parentDirective',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {

      controller.foo = function() {
        return "overrided";
      }

    },
    compile: function(element, attr) {
      attr.attr2 = "attr2";
    }
  }
});
```

Whole thing can be easily done by using child scope instead of isolated.
Or by using extending by template. But if I extends directive with template I would have to copy parent "scope" and "template" definition to child-directive and forward all the non-default attributes this doesn't seem like an elegant solution.

So the key question, is there a way to override parent-directive function using isolated scope without forwarding attributes.

Here is the [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/7esBbGG1ysIuXcZhqMoY?p=info)

Comment: Have you tried using $parent? If your functions are in the parent scope you can access them using $parent and after that override them.

Comment: Yes indeed, but what if there would be ng-if directive somewhere between parent and child directive. Using $parent IMHO isn't a solution here. Despite the fact that $parent is considered as bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have done some research and it turns out that there can be several approaches there

**Scope inheritance**

Since child-directive is not creating own scope it just creating new methods at parent-directive parent scope. So we can modify attributes during compile and specify overridden foo method.

```
app.directive('parentDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      fooImpl: '&?',
      // lots of attrs
    },
    controller: function($scope) {

      $scope.foo = function() {
        if ($scope.fooImpl) {
          return $scope.fooImpl();
        }
        return "not overrided";
      }

    },
    template: '<div class="some-styling"><main-directive foo="foo()"></main-directive></div>'
  }
});

app.directive('childDirective', function() {

  return {
    scope: false,
    require: 'parentDirective',
    controller: function($scope) {

      $scope.foo = function() {
        return "overrided";
      }

    },
    compile: function(element, attr) {
      attr.fooImpl = "foo()";
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the [DEMO1](https://plnkr.co/edit/7esBbGG1ysIuXcZhqMoY?p=preview)

**Add to isolated scope**

Angular provides special function. That can get isolated scope from element. So we can override our method during linking phase.

```
app.directive('parentDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      fooImpl: '&?',
      // lots of attrs
    },
    controller: function($scope) {

      $scope.foo = function() {
        if ($scope.fooImpl) {
          return $scope.fooImpl();
        }
        return "not overrided";
      }

    },
    template: '<div class="some-styling"><main-directive foo="foo()"></main-directive></div>'
  }
});

app.directive('childDirective', function() {

  return {
    scope: false,
    require: 'parentDirective',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      var innerScope = angular.element(element[0]).isolateScope();
      innerScope.foo = function() {
        return "overrided";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the [DEMO2](https://plnkr.co/edit/shrtXJ1s0baiZkbnOZ6e?p=preview)

**Controller method**

If we use controllerAs syntax. That means we exposing controller object variables as a scope. We can override function  in child directive during linking phase.

```
app.directive('parentDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      fooImpl: '&?',
      // lots of attrs
    },
    controller: function($scope) {

      var vm = this;

      vm.foo = function() {
        return "not overrided";
      }

    },
    controllerAs : 'vm',
    template: '<div class="some-styling"><main-directive foo="vm.foo()"></main-directive></div>'
  }
});

app.directive('childDirective', function() {

  return {
    scope: false,
    require: 'parentDirective',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {

       controller.foo = function() {
        return "overrided";
      }


    }
  }
});
```

Here is the [DEMO3](https://plnkr.co/edit/gwUGTiTwHOjmaVn5PsH9?p=preview)

**Transclusion**

Practically you can do the same thing with seperate parent and child directive and using transclusion. But anyway it would be combination of above approaches. Thanks for ["Extending an existing directive in AngularJS"](http://thaiat.github.io/blog/2014/03/10/extending-an-existing-directive-in-angularjs/)