# How to intercept a function in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive called "my-dir" that I can't modified inside my project

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <my-dir>
    <button ng-click="doSomething()">Click it</button>
  </my-dir>
</div>
```

I need to do some checks before invoking doSomething function. I can't modified anything inside my-dir directive. Is there a way to intercept into MyCtrl the ng-click on the button?

Comment: Create your own function, make your checks, then call doSomething(). Replace the ng-click with that function.

Comment: I can't replace the function into ng-click

Comment: "I can't replace the function into ng-click" why not?

Comment: Can you pass the function into the new function I suggested? ng-click="newFunction($event, doSomething)". If you can't modify the directive I don't see a way to accomplish what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Aren't you in control of `doSomething`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly,

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-if = "[Function or variable] -> This can be an option to hide the button">
        <my-dir>
            <button ng-click="doSomething()">Click it</button>
        </my-dir>
    </div>
```

or you can override the directive but it is gonna be a bit more complex. You can check the following link, there is also a demo which can be helpful if you choose this way. [AngularJS override directive controller function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896567/angularjs-override-directive-controller-function)